# Bash syntax error: "[[: not found"

Tags: bash

I'm working with a bash script that is currently working on a server (RHEL4). I'm developing on my laptop with Ubuntu 10.04, but I don't think the platform is causing the problem.

Here's what's happening:
I have a skeleton script that calls another script that does most of the work. However, it makes calls to getConfig.sh a lot. getConfig.sh basically just parses some command line argument (using getopts) and calls a Java program to parse some XML files. Anyways, getConfig.sh is throwing up lots of errors (but still seems to work).

Here's the message that I'm getting

> getconfig.sh: 89: [[: not found
>   getconfig.sh: 89: [[: not found
>   getconfig.sh: 94: [[: not found

I get those three errors every time it runs; however, the script completes and the Java code runs.

Here's the relavent code section

```
parseOptions $*

if [[ "${debugMode}" == "true" ]] ; then
    DEBUG="-DDEBUG=true"
    echo "${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java ${DEBUG} -Djava.endorsed.dirs=${JAXP_HOME} -jar $(dirname $0)/GetXPath.jar ${XML_File} ${XPath_Query}"
fi
```

Line 89 is "parseOptions $* and line 94 is "fi"

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: As an aside, `$*` is buggy -- it'll change two arguments `"argument one" "argument two"` into four agruments, `"argument" "one" "argument" "two"`. Instead, use `"$@"`.

Comment: @AntonioMoreno That's a terrible idea!!! Don't do this!!!

Answer (score 202, accepted):

If your script is executable and you are executing it like `./getconfig.sh`, the first line of your script needs to be:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Without that shebang line, your script will be interpreted by `sh` which doesn't understand `[[` in `if` statements.

Otherwise, you should run your script like `bash getconfig.sh`, **not** `sh getconfig.sh`. Even if your default shell is bash, scripts run with `sh` will use a reduced set of bash's features, in order to be more compliant with the POSIX standard. `[[` is one of the features that is disabled.

Comment: Thanks Dennis. The dufus who originally wrote this code used #!/bin/sh on all the scripts. I missed changing this one.

Comment: I am seeing this same issue, but i have `#!/bin/bash` at the top of my script.

Comment: I figured out the issue. If you are calling the script from another script make sure you are using `bash nameofscript.sh` instead of `sh nameofscript.sh`.

Comment: Ugh.. Thanks for pointing out the obvious. Mine said #!/bin/sh. How did that get there?!

Comment: `$ sudo rm /bin/sh` and execute `$ sudo ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh`

Comment: @AntonioMoreno: This could cause issues and would likely be reverted during a system update. It's better to not delete the file and put the symlink in `/usr/local/bin` and have that directory earlier in your `PATH` than `/bin`.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Thank you , this is one of those thing that you need to look for when the hours are getting long...

Comment: @AntonioMoreno, Bash has a built-in feature where it will run in POSIX-mode if it's executed as `sh`. So, your "trick" doesn't help. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html

Answer (score 49):

Use:

`bash scriptname.sh`

instead of:

`sh scriptname.sh`

Comment: If you want to learn the difference between sh and bash, you can take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5725402/5672563

Answer (score -3):

If you are checking for equality, shouldn't the if be ?

`if [[ "${debugMode}" = "true" ]]; then
....
fi`

Comment: In Bash, in this context, `==` and `=` are interchangeable.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer