# Bash script to check if file exists in another directory (incld subdirectory)

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a script to compare files in one directory against another (including sub-directories) & see if they exist. What I have so far is:

```
#!/bin/sh

# This will compare files in 'dropbox>camera uploads' against pics in local 'pictures' folder.
# If present they are moved to 'duplicate' folder if not to 'not_duplicate' inside dropbox
#
# Mar '20
#
#

DROPBOX_LOC="/home/unencrypted/Dropbox/CameraUploads"
DROPBOX_LOC_DUPLICATE="/home/unencrypted/Dropbox/CameraUploads/duplicate"
DROPBOX_LOC_NOT_DUPLICATE="/home/unencrypted/Dropbox/CameraUploads/not_duplicate"
PICS_LOC="/home/user/Pictures"

for file in $DROPBOX_LOC/*
# NOTE: Use of " " preserves whitespace in single variable!

do
    echo "Checking for: $file"
    #ls -l $file

   if [[ -f "$PICS_LOC/${file##*/}" ]]
        then
        echo "$file is a duplicate"
        # Move to duplicate folder
        continue
     else
        echo "$file is a NOT a duplicate"
        # Move to not duplicate folder
        fi
done
exit 0
```

But this returns:

```
Checking for: /home/unencrypted/Dropbox/CameraUploads/2015-11-07 16.58.49.jpg
./delete_dropbox_pics.sh: 22: ./delete_dropbox_pics.sh: [[: not found
/home/unencrypted/Dropbox/CameraUploads/2015-11-07 16.58.49.jpg is a NOT a duplicate
```

Can anyone please suggest a fix (including how to search sub-directories)?

Comment: Single square brackets? Your `continue` is redundant.

Comment: Validate your script, via https://shellcheck.net, You're using `sh` as the shebang but your test is using `[[` which does not exists in `POSIX sh`. any how that link will good for you.

Comment: Btw., if you really want to check for exact duplicates, you might want --beside the filename-- to check e.g. on `md5sum`'s.

Comment: Oh, change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: There are apps written to find duplicates, to name a few, `fdupes` and `rmlint` and good luck for reinventing the wheel :-)

Comment: in additional to replace [[ ]] with [ ] in your if constructions, "for file in $DROPBOX_LOC/*" and  "including sub-directories" will not works, you should use find command, which can recursively find the files in subdirectories.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash syntax error: "\[\[: not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401183/bash-syntax-error-not-found)

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I actually stumbled across FSlint Janitor which does does what I want. I corrected some of my mistakes but looks like I need to move to using find as pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `diff` command.

```
diff -r <directory1> <directory2>
```

> -r, --recursive
>                 recursively compare any subdirectories found

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the Dropbox is a small subset of the picture folder, I'm trying to see what duplicates exist in the Dropbox folder