# commit-msg hook gives "[[: not found" error

Tags: git-commit, pre-commit-hook

My .git/hooks/commit-msg file looks like

```
#!/bin/sh
COMMIT_MSG_FILE=$1
comm_msg=$(head -l $COMMIT_MSG_FILE)
if [[ $comm_msg =~ ^TASKID-[\d]+ ]]; then
  exit 0
else
  echo "Commit message must start with task id." >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

But when I run

```
git commit -m "test commit"
```

I get the error ".git/hooks/commit-msg: 4: .git/hooks/commit-msg: [[: not found. I can't see anything wrong with my syntax. What could be causing this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash syntax error: "\[\[: not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401183/bash-syntax-error-not-found)

Comment: As an aside, you might want to put anything that can be expanded (such as `$` or `*` parameters) in quotes so they aren't interpreted as part of the command line being executed (e.g. if `COMMIT_MSG_FILE` or `comm_msg` have spaces or valid shell operators).

Comment: Ah, #!/bin/bash instead of sh. Subtle difference I missed!